# Purpose of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\<SID> - "IsUpgrade"

Tags: windows, windows-registry, user-profiles

I just came across a workstation with MANY keys under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion. I'm familiar with the ProfileList and ProfileGUID subkeys, but was srpprised to see so many SID entries at the same level:

[image]

Anyone know the purpose of these keys, and what if they were deleted?

Comment: It appears to be a list of GUID for users indicating if the profile had been logged into after an upgrade (21H2 or 22H2) more than likely. Can you confirm if you have multiple users on the machine?